# Python converting UUID's from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

I have a text file that includes UUIDS that all look like this:

```
A4AB4CD2-016B-411E-8BA1-0000C592BF17
```

When I try and parse/print the file with python, most (but not all) end up looking like this:

```
12:40:54:457
```

There are three chunks per line that I'm parsing, a double, a date, and this uuid.  The first two parts work fine.  The relevant lines of code are:

```
for line in fileLines:

    parts = line.split()
    # Parse first two chunks
    outputFile.write(""" WHERE tableID = '""" + uuid.UUID(parts[2]) + """'""")
```

This fails because the UUIDs are already of the form 12:40:54:547, but I don't know what this sub-type of UUID is called, let alone how to appropriately parse it.  My goal is simply to read in the uuid exactly as it is, and re-print it with some extra text around it so I can run it as an SQL script.

I'm running python 3.3.2

A full line of input looks like this:

```
339.00  2013-06-18 12:40:54.457 A4AB4CD2-016B-411E-8BA1-0000C592BF17
```

Comment: Looks like your line.split() splits in a datetime. Do you have a full input line for us.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/N0C11Q

Comment: On a related matter, it looks like you're generating SQL by concatenating strings containing user input. Don't do that.

Comment: Now that you've shown a line of input, the problem is obvious. You have *two* date/time fields, so the UUID is in `parts[3]`.

Comment: The generated text file came out of SQL already.  I kind of already made mistake and I'm just trying to re-insert data that I mistakenly removed.

Comment: @MarkRansom wow.  I feel silly.

Comment: Silly maybe, but don't sweat over it too much. We all have blind spots and/or bad days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the UUID will always be last in the line, access it with [-1]

```
outputFile.write(""" WHERE tableID = '""" + uuid.UUID(parts[-1]) + """'""")
```

In the example you give parts[2] will always return the time. If your lines are consistent, you can use parts[2], but if the data up to the UUID varies, just always pick the last element after the split

Comment: more precisely, parts[0] is 339.00, parts[1] is the date, parts[2] is the time and the uuid is parts[3]

Comment: Yep, thanks.  I guess I was thinking to fast that double, datetime, and uuid would necessarily equal 3 parts.  Also, I didn't know you can access the last element with [-1].  So thanks for that tidbit as well.

Comment: Sure thing, it may be worth noting that you can also use [-2] to get the second to last element, [-3] to get the third last, etc

Answer (score -1):

string.split() is a magic , you wont need to specify your delimiter it will split.

> > > part = "339.00  2013-06-18 12:40:54.457 A4AB4CD2-016B-411E-8BA1-0000C592BF17"
> > >
> > > part.split() ; part.split(" ")  # does the same.

['339.00', '2013-06-18', '12:40:54.457', 'A4AB4CD2-016B-411E-8BA1-0000C592BF17']

['339.00', '', '2013-06-18', '12:40:54.457', 'A4AB4CD2-016B-411E-8BA1-0000C592BF17']

My opinion is use str(part.split()[-1]).

Regarding UUID use string conversion while converting into UUID see below for your reference. ( or it may cause issue )

> > > uuid.UUID("A4AB4CD2-016B-411E-8BA1-0000C592BF17")

UUID('a4ab4cd2-016b-411e-8ba1-0000c592bf17')

> > > str(uuid.UUID("A4AB4CD2-016B-411E-8BA1-0000C592BF17"))

'a4ab4cd2-016b-411e-8ba1-0000c592bf17'

So it can be like this.

for line in fileLines:

```
parts = line.split()

# Parse first two chunks

outputFile.write(""" WHERE tableID = '""" + str(uuid.UUID(parts[-1])) + """'""")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I was already using str.split() with no argument to split on whitespace.  I also ended up not needing uuid.UUID() at all because that was not the issue.  I was in fact trying to parse the second half of the date-time object as the uuid.